# how to plot multiple locations in google.map using flask

Tags: python

i'm traying to showing multiple points in map from a csv file named 'likibularochelle_test.csv' this file contains 866 points with latitude and longitude but i can't view all of this points just 33 as a matter of fact i plot just the first 33 point from my csv file , i don't now why , maybe the numbre of requests to googleApi ? I managed this code as below :

```
Longitude1=[]
Latitude1=[] 
with open('likibularochelle_test.csv') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csv_reader) # supression des entêtes
        for row in csv_reader:
            Longitude1.append(row[0])
            Latitude1.append(row[1])

fullmap = Map(
            zoom=4,
            identifier="fullmap",
            varname="fullmap",
            style=(
                "height:100%;"
                "width:100%;"
                "top:0;"
                "left:0;"
                "position:absolute;"
                "z-index:200;"
            ),
            lat= 46.160329 ,
            lng=-1.151139,
            markers=[(lat,lng) for lat,lng in zip(Latitude1,Longitude1)
            ]
            fit_markers_to_bounds = True

        )
    return render_template('example_fullmap.html', fullmap=fullmap)
```

here is the output image :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated